# group by count and sum based on particular column in pandas dataframe in separate column along with other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df):

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
A1  B1  c   10  E1  F1
A2  B2  c   50  E2  F2
A3  B3  c   20  E2  F3
A4  B4  c   30  E1  F4
A5  B5  c   40  E3  F5
```

Output should be like;

```
df:
A   B   C   D   E   F   count   sum
A1  B1  c   10  E1  F1  2   40
A2  B2  c   50  E2  F2  2   70
A3  B3  c   20  E2  F3  2   70
A4  B4  c   30  E1  F4  2   40
A5  B5  c   40  E3  F5  1   40
```

taking count and sum based on E column.

I tried :

```
df.groupby('E').agg(['count','sum'])
```

I am getting only count and sum column not other columns of `df`.
Please suggest the solution.

Comment: `df.groupby('E').agg({'column1': 'count', 'column2': 'sum'})`

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('E')['E'].transform('count')
df['sum'] = df.groupby('E')['D'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
    A   B  C   D   E   F  count  sum
0  A1  B1  c  10  E1  F1      2   40
1  A2  B2  c  50  E2  F2      2   70
2  A3  B3  c  20  E2  F3      2   70
3  A4  B4  c  30  E1  F4      2   40
4  A5  B5  c  40  E3  F5      1   40
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your data, but what you want to do is :

```
df.groupby('E').agg({'column1': 'count', 'column2': 'sum'})
```

Comment: I want other columns as well of the dataframe df along with sum and count coulmn.